# Mysql simple query and values in a column but wrong SUM result

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Query:

```
SELECT SUM(USDamount) as totalsales
FROM invoice_table 
WHERE DATE LIKE '2014-01-%'
```

shows `3927.3400` as result

but when I calculate real result manuall, it is `5117.54`

Previously field type was varchar(12) now I changed it to decimal(10,5)  but result is still the same.

When I run following query:

```
(SELECT * 
FROM invoice_table 
WHERE DATE LIKE '2014-01-%');
```

which is same excep here I used `SELECT *` instead of `select SUM(USDamount)`

Following values are displayed in result and manual total of these values is different than SUM function calculated values:

```
 509
 75
 20
 250
 75
 35
 20
 90
 30
 51
 567
 80
 185
 20
 40
 480
 40
 60
 80
 70
 1191.2
 40
 45.24
 113.4
 210
 42.7
 510
 188
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

=================================================================

Here is complete table structure:

```
Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
1   id  mediumint(9)            No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  Change Change   Drop Drop   

2   username    varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

3   date    datetime            No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

4   ptransactionid  varchar(150)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

5   paymethod   tinytext    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

6   amount  decimal(10,4)           No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

7   USDamount   decimal(10,4)           No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

8   paidincurrency  varchar(5)  latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

9   paidfororders   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

10  paidby  text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

11  status  varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

12  chargedvia  varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop   

13  remainingamountcredit   varchar(12) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        Change Change   Drop Drop
```

Also there is no typing mistake. These values were automatically inserted by merchant account website after successful payment via success URL. I exported the result of select * from .... and calculated via excel sum result of column USDamount and result was accurate so this confirms no typing mistake. Please help. This is driving me crazy as I have already tried everything to make sum work correctly :(

Comment: That doesn't add up...  Can you add the date field to your sample?  Can't re-create the problem, sum of those numbers works without issue.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c87f2/1/0

Comment: ... why would a dollar amount be stored as character data in the first place? Note that, as your `Date` column should be a date/time/timestamp type, you'd be better off querying it like `date >= CAST('2014-01-01' as DATE) AND date < CAST('2014-02-01' as DATE)` which will be able to use an index (will run **MUCH** faster on large databases).  It would appear that a row with `USDollar = 1190.2` is being excluded for some reason... do you have a typo somewhere?  Is the row with `1191.2` different for some reason?

Comment: My reply to your comments was too big so I edited the original post above and replied there. I also provided complete table structure. Please help. Thanks!